# When should I call done() in node-postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, socket.io, pg, node-postgres

pg 4.4.3
I'm using socket.io to connect client-side to server. I've guessed, I suppose to connect server to database on server start, but there are a lot of warnings in pg "docs": 'use done() or bad things will happen'.
When should i use it? If i'm opening connection to the db and then creating socket.io server within it, and then using `done()` after each query, then i'm receiving error after 30 sec idle:
`Error: This socket has been ended by the other party`
May be I should create socket.io and then open connection to the db within each user session? or open connection to db on each query if it's not currently opened? Being honest, I don't get, why should i do this, why can't I just create single connection to the database on server start and send all queries through it instead of this open-close repetition.

Comment: `done` should be called after you execute the query. Check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), which guarantees to call `done` correctly when it is needed.

Comment: the question is: how should I act within socket.io session. I don't think, I need more libraries - I just need to use this `done()` function properly

Comment: right now, during development, i call `done()` only at the session end (socket.io client disconnect i mean). It works perfectly, but I'm not sure this is correct approach